# How to alter Fields of Field Collection?

Tags: entities

I have a field collection in a custom Content Type.

I wanted to do form alter.

I'm unable to locate the fields of field collection in hook_form_alter(), do we have any other way ?

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: Also, are you aware that fields on field collections aren't ACTUALLY part of the host entity?  They are entities in their own right embedded into a parent entity.

Answer (score 2):

try to use 
`$form['YOUR_field_collection']['und']['0']['sub_field']['und']['0']['value']`
for ex : to add ['#autocomplete_path'] would :
`$form['YOUR_field_collection']['und']['0']['sub_field']['und']['0']['value']'#autocomplete_path']=''`

Answer (score 1):

It is available in the hook_form_alter(). I missed them

```
   /*
   * Implements hook_form_alter()
   */
   function digitaliq_user_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){   
   // Id of the field collection 'field_bck_fld1'
   $form['field_bck_fld1'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]

   }
```